# Is there a way to use the keyboard as mouse without ease of access?

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, mouse

I'm using Windows 10 and I'm playing Grim Dawn. I don't want to click to death and develop tendinitis, so I always have the ease of access enabled to click with the numpad, but that doesn't work in some games. There's a software called "X-Mouse Button Control" which allows you to use the keyboard with the mouse, but is there a software to do the opposite? Suppose I want to left click using alt or the S key, how would I do that? Would I have to develop custom software to capture the events and do that? There must be something to do it.

Comment: for software suggestion try [softwarerecs.se]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/). You'll need to install the software and then right click > new > autohotkey script.

Then you can experiment with the limitless things this software can do for you at home and also at work. You can perform simple re-maps or you can go as far as creating your own macro scripts that perform a series of actions when hitting a single key. The choice is yours. Once your script is created, test it works then when you're finished simply run the script then launch your game.

[This page](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm) covers mouse, keyboard and joystick remapping.

Comment: This software is brilliant, I did not know it. It didn't work though with the game in question. I wrote a script to click with the 'h' key and worked on the desktop, but not in the game, probably for the same reason why the ease of access doesn't work. I've noticed this discrepancy in many games, as it works with some of them and not the others. Must have something to do with how the event is captured in the low-level api, and it varies from game to game. Thanks anyway, this software might prove useful for something else entirely :)

Comment: BLOODY HELL! I've managed to make it work! I've found the difference, I had to use "Send {LButton}" instead of just LButton. There's a slight low-level difference that I'm not quite sure what it is, but this software is so amazing that it allows you to do that. THANKS!

Comment: Glad to hear it's helped! The possibilities with this software is limitless. The spy cursor tool allows you to capture exact points on the screen and even script those into automated mouse clicks. I play a lot of command and conquer (old school i know) and I've got all my F1, F2, F3 keys to batch train various troops. F1 = train 10 of these guys, 4 of those guys, 20 of these other guys. Enjoy!